# Select does not auto update on ng-model change rendered using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating dropdown in a directive as follows:

```
<select ng-model="selectedSite">
    <option value="new">Add New Site</option>
    <option value="line" disabled>------------------------</option>
    <option ng-repeat="site in defaultSites"
            value="{{$index}}">
        {{site.name}}
    </option>
 </select>
```

Directive is:

```
app.directive('siteForm', function() {
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        site: '=',        
        defaultSites: '=',
        selectedSite: '=',

    },
    templateUrl: '/views/templates/site_form.html',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

    $scope.$watch('selectedSite', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log('Site selected:', newValue);
            if (newValue !== undefined && newValue !== null) {
                if (newValue !== "new") {
                    var value = $scope.defaultSites[parseInt(newValue)];
                    $scope.site.name = value.name;
                } else {
                    $scope.site.name = "";
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

However when I provide the initial index in selectedSite, it does not work and always shows first option. E.g. If we provide the selectedSite as "1" then option with value "1" should get selected which is not happening.

Everything else works fine including $watch and selectedSite gets populated when I select option from dropdown.

I am using AngularJS v1.2.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use ng-selected in following way

```
<option ng-repeat="site in defaultSites" value="{{$index}}" ng-selected="{{$index == selectedSite}}">
        {{site.name}}
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `$scope.$apply()` at the end of your `$watch` handler.

See [the AngularJS docs on Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope).